# how to give permission to user on their own pods pages content with 'add' and 'edit' options only?

Tags: php, podscms

How to give permission to user on their own pods pages content with 'add' and 'edit' options only?  I am using PHP, Apache, MySql and  wordpress.
Please, give me code examples.

I am using following code:

```
<?php 
$object = new Pod('dreams');
$object->ui = array('title' => 'My Pod' ,'add_fields' => array('name' ,'position','photo','bio','eom'),'edit_fields' => array('name' ,'position','photo','bio','eom','approved'));
    //load Pod
    $pod = new Pod('dreams');

    if(current_user_can('administrator')) {
        //set publicForm() visible fields for admins
       $object->ui = array('title' => 'My Dream' ,'add_fields' => array('name' ,'position','photo','bio','eom'),'edit_fields' => array('name' ,'position','photo','bio','eom','approved'));
    pods_ui_manage($object);
    } else if(is_user_logged_in()) {
    // Get the last URL variable
    $slug = pods_url_variable('1');
    $Edit = new Pod('team', $slug);
    $name = $Edit->get_field('name');
    $author_id = $Edit->get_field('author_id'); // GET AUTHOR FROM POD
     $user_id = $current_user->ID;
    global $current_user;   // GET USER INFO
    get_currentuserinfo();
$object->ui = array('title' => 'My Dream' ,'add_fields' => array('name' ,'position','photo','bio','eom'),'edit_fields' => array('name' ,'position','photo','bio','eom','approved'));
    pods_ui_manage($object);
 // $edit_listing = (($author_id == $current_user->ID) || (current_user_can('manage_options') == true) ? true : false); //

}; ?> <br/><br/>
<table>
<div><h1>Create a Dream</h1>
<p>What is this Dream, what do I want to do, accomplish, achieve?</p>
<p>Does this Dream involve someone else?</p>
<p>What tools are available to help achieve this Dream?</p>
<p>What steps can I take to help me achieve this Dream?</p>

<?php  $pod->publicForm($fields); ?>
</div></table>
```

Now the user can also see and edit all other user posts. But this should not be so.

Answer (score 0):

In your "ui" array, you want to add an additional 'where' and 'edit_where' clause.

```
'where' => 'p.author_id = ' . $user_id,
'edit_where' => array('author_id' => $user_id)
```